# Could nmap local network scan affect network general speed and/or performance?

Tags: networking, monitoring, nmap

For the past few days I've been trying to monitor my local network to look for new device connections. At first I thought of **arpwatch**, but if I'm not mistaken, it is worthless if not running on the router itself, which I cannot do.

So then I thought of **nmap**, and it does work. I'm currently using this specific command with sudo: `nmap -sP MY_NETWORK_IP`. But at this point I'm wondering, if I make for example a cron task to run it every minute, will affect my local network? I mean, in terms of speed and/or general performance. The scan finishes in like 5 seconds, btw.

Also, I guess not, but can nmap report recently connected, but now disconnected devices?

Or is there another simple network monitoring solution you guys can think of?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It could, but unless your network is ancient (speeds unter 1Mbit/s) you will not notice any effects. Detecting new clients is not a good task for another client, it should be done by the routers or switches.

Comment: Unfortunately, my router is a veeeeeeeeeeeeery limited one provided by the ISP, so I can't do much on it, and I'm not gonna but a router just for this. I do have a server that is always on so my plan is to put a docker for this task. My internal network is 1Gbps and my internet contract is of 600Mbps, so I guess I won't notice anything on any device?

Can you think of other alternative with my current setup (basically a shitty router)?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to protect your network from foreign devices (like somebody connecting a machine to a LAN port), there are really only two options: either MAC whitelisting (easy to bypass) or full 802.1x, but both of these are probably not supported by your router.

Comment: That's right, it's not supported. MAC filterins is also NOT an option for me, some of my devices has random virtual MACs, and also, every time a friend or family member came to my house I would have to stop and authorize their MAC, which is a pain in the ass. My network is fairly secure, but sometimes a I see MACs I don't recognize, so I'm looking for something to send me an email when a new MAC is found.

Any other alternative besides using nmap - cron - ssmtp? Would that have any impact on any device communication or whatever?

Comment: So, is it viable, or would be a performance-consuming thing? Any alternatives?

Comment: You will hardly noticably stress any modern network with your approach. But it is not without fault - if a system on your network has no open ports and does not respond to ICMP requests, your approach will *not be able to find it*. The only 100% solution is on the network level, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, I know is not 100% reliable, but it's something :/

Can you think of an alternative with my configuration?

Comment: No. <filler content because a comment needs 12 chars>

Comment: OK then, I'll think about it. Thanks all!